# ios Cancel NSURLConnection Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have the following code:

```
func getStoryContent( cityID : String, completionHandler: (loaded: Bool, dataNil: Bool) -> ()) -> () {
    let scriptUrl = "***"
    var user_id = "nil"
    if let userID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userId") {
        user_id = userID
    }
    var params =  ***
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: scriptUrl);
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let data = params.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.timeoutInterval = 10
    request.HTTPBody=data
    request.HTTPShouldHandleCookies=false
    let queue:NSOperationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        do {
            ....code.....
```

This runs in the background when displaying a slideshow of images to the user, it basically downloads more images to be displayed and appends them to the array of images. The issue is that the user can exit the slideshow at anytime, in this event I need to cancel this `NSURLConnection`. I have a function which is executed when the user wants to exit the slideshow, but I'm not sure what code to add to it to properly cancel this connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSURLConnection`'s `sendAsynchronousRequest` is not a cancelable request. But `NSURLConnection` is deprecated, anyway, and you should use `NSURLSession`. And `NSURLSession`'s `dataTask` is cancelable.

So, instead of:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue) { response, data, error in
    do {
        ....code.....
    } 
}
```

You can use:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    do {
        ....code.....
    } 
}
task.resume()
```

And, if you need to cancel it, you can do `task.cancel()`.

Comment: Can I still use the completion Handler with that, it is a required part of code for me

Comment: Yes, just as I illustrated above. Note, the order of the parameters is different, though, with `data` first. But other than that, it's very similar. Regarding the queue, the `sharedSession` defaults to a serial background queue (but you can instantiate your own `NSURLSession` using a `NSURLSessionConfiguration` if you want to specify your own queue). But the default background queue should probably be fine.